Should I increase my deposit on a house by taking money out of my S&P investment?
I am in the process of buying a house. The total price of the house is £185,000.
I have got a £70,000 deposit, which would mean I take out a mortgage of £115,000.
I also have £23,000 invested in to the S&P500.
My question is, am I better off increasing my deposit by adding this £23,000, or leaving it in my stocks and shares ISA, letting it grow?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Could you add the expected interest rate for your mortgage and your expected rate of return for your investments? The maximum mortgage payment you could comfortably afford is also relevant.

Why are you considering this? What are your tradeoffs? In addition to what @Tashus mentioned you should also consider how much emergency funds you have (general advice is to have about half a year worth of expenses), you don't want to not have any liquid net worth at all.

Much depends upon your situation and as such this advice is kind of generic and loaded with contingencies.
If you had a healthy and secure income; and, you could gather the full 185K, I would buy it in cash.  This would avoid a lot of costs with having a mortgage.  However, by your numbers you are off by 47k. Sizable, but surprisingly close.
Given that you have to take a mortgage I might advise to put less down (maybe like 100K) and put 15K in a high yield savings account as an emergency fund.  This would be especially true if your income is not as certain or you are a first time homeowner.
If repairs or updates are "needed", I might hold more back than the 15K previously cited from the down payment and use that money for those repairs/updates.
In general I would tend to leave the 23K in the S&P500 fund as its sale would tend to generate a largish tax bill depending upon your profit.

I would say the healthier and more secure the income, the more beneficial to take on a mortgage [deferring taxes on sale of investments + prioritizing long-term investing rather than interest cost reduction]. Not always safe / the right thing, of course, depending on a person's risk tolerance.

The money is described as being in a stocks and shares ISA so there would be no tax bill. In theory taking money out of an ISA means you are losing out on a tax-free allowance you could use in future, but since you can add £20K/year , this is not really a big issue here.
